# Get refresh token expiry from Microsoft Identity

Tags: .net, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-identity-platform

I am making a request to the [Microsoft Identity Platform token endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token) to renew my refresh and access tokens. I would like to know when the refresh token will expire so I can ensure I always have a valid token. However I cannot find a way to identify the expiry of the refresh token in the payload. I have included the offline_access scope so I receive the refresh token but I am not able to decode the refresh token as it is not a valid JWT and there is no property which specifies the expiry of the refresh token.

I know the expiry is currently configured to 90 days so I could set it manually in my code, however I would like a more robust solution in case that configuration changes.

Comment: Why do you need it? Typically we use a refresh token to renew a pair of new access token  and new refresh token. When the new access token expires, we should use the new refresh token to renew again. It is impossible for a new refresh token to expire. So I think you don't need to handle the expiry time of refresh token.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm trying to cater for the case where an access token is not retrieved for the lifespan of the refresh token and causing the refresh token to expire after 90 days. In my case this would occur if the user does not use the application for over 90 days.

Comment: So you want to use the refresh token to renew  before it will expire nearly 90 days? But requiring the user to reenter their credentials should be reasonable if they don't use the app for such a long time.

Comment: If you use MSAL.net , you will need to call the `AcquireTokenSilent` method. See reference here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-acquire-token-silently.